# Installing NetLogo on Windows 10.

Tags: windows-10, netlogo

I am trying to install NetLogo 6.0.1 in a Windows 10, 64 bits, but the installer says that the "administrator has set policies to prevent this install". I tried running the msi installer, but it says that the program is not compatible. Anyone has the same issue? Can I install from an executable, instead of a msi?

Comment: You may need administrator privileges to install. (?)
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#windowswarning

Comment: I do have administrator privileges. It happens that, in windows 7 or previous, when you click on the msi the system asks whether you allow the program to install with administrator priviliges, but in Windows 10 it does not. As the file is not executable it calls the msiservice, which even running as administrator does not install.

Comment: I just retried the installer on Win 10.  It works fine.  Perhaps you are using an account without admin privileges, without realizing it.  More likely, from your report, you downloaded the wrong version for you OS.  (Finally, but very unlikely, you can try `cmd /c assoc .msi` in powershell to make sure you have the proper association to the file extension.)  Oh, I suppose you can check that you have access to the service: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1746379/longer-install-msi-files-windows-installer-service-accessed.html

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it. The problem was my antivirus (as suggested in the documentation). I have Comodo Antivirus 10, which has a feature called "auto-containment". I tried installing with the antivirus disabled, but the "auto-containment" was still active and blocking the program from installing. Just disabling this feature temporarily worked.